# AzureAD can't authorize users from another ADs. Is there a way?

Tags: azure, onedrive, azure-active-directory

We are developing a feature for our application to integrate with OneDrive for Business using [Onedrive API](https://dev.onedrive.com).

For this we had to register our application in AzureAD. When people in our company sign into the application it works fine because all of our users are in the same AD that the application was created.

Other people can't authenticate and get this error.

```
Additional technical information: 
Correlation ID: a1091720-d28d-4f59-abc3-c6b7bbec3bdf 
Timestamp: 2016-02-26 09:22:54Z 
AADSTS70001: Application with identifier '9280bd79-XX-XX-XXXXXXXX6c3' was not found in the directory XXXXXX.com
```

But we need to let people from any organization to use OneDrive feature  of our application.

How can i get this done?.

Comment: Have you made your application multi-tenant?

Comment: did you take a look at Azure B2B for this already? is it a paas thingy?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes I have. I think it solved that problem.

Comment: Oh, boys, how can you be so fast. Yes, the app should be created as Multi-tenant in Azure AD. As for B2B - it would not help in that case. B2B has another use case.